# How to make `Wakeup` plugins work?

Tags: plugins, weather, wakeup

`Wakeup` application is meant to greet a user at specific time, saying things like current wind and temperature outside. But I can't get how to make the thing work on Ubuntu: what am I meant to install for weather information to be provided correctly (all the Wakeup plugins are installed and turned on, their settings don't offer anything to help). I use XUbuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the version released with Precise (wakeup 1.2). This version will also work in Oneiric, although at this point is not in the oneiric repositories. The newer one should be a lot more stable, and has been particularly updated with respect to the weather plugin: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wakeup/+bug/891033